# Ajax approach to populating a second dynamic dropdown based on the selection in the first

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I've not used much Ajax before, and this seems simple. I have the seperate parts to the puzzle, but not sure how to put them together.

Both dropdowns are populated from the database, the first is populated using the following code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT title, nid FROM node where type= 'hotel'";
$hotels = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<select name="hotels" id="hotels">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($hotels))
{
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['nid']."\">".$row['title']."\n  ";
}
?>
</select>
```

The second dropdown should be populated based on the value selected above. So basically I want to take the id of the selected item and then use that in a query to populate the second dropdown.

I would use the above code, but with the following for the SQL query:

```
SELECT title, nid from node where type = 'season' AND hotel_nid = X
```

Where X is the id of the selectedIndex on the first dropdown.

Althought the code is there to work, I don't know how to combine the two. I could use Javascript to modify the InnerHTML of a div called "seasons" by printing the code to retrieve and display the dropdowns.

But is there a better way where I can have both the dropdowns visible, but the second is disabled until the first is completed?

Comment: Hi, I have now setup jQuery and testing it is working in my page with a simple script. Could you tell me what is the easiest way with jQuery to achieve what I need? I would take more time to investigate but this is due to a client earlier than expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script populating the second list should be called through Ajax when the user changes the value of the first dropdown. So you should add onchange="myFunctionToPopulate(this.value);" to the first dropdown.

If you don't know how to do that I'd suggest also you use a JS library such as jQuery, and we will post you the simple code to achieve this.

**Edited**

With jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
<select name="first_dropdown" onchange="$('#dropdown2_container').load('your_script.php?nid='+this.value);">
  <option....
</select>
...
<div id="dropdown2_container" style="display:none"> </div>
```

Where your_script.php would return the whole select tag.

Comment: I know about setting onChange(), however the problem i've came up against is when trying to set the innerHTML to display the 2nd drop down, when setting innerHTML in Javascript you can't use Parentheses in the middle of a js variable, i've tried escape characters etc

Comment: Hi, I have now setup jQuery and testing it is working in my page with a simple script. Could you tell me what is the easiest way with jQuery to achieve what I need? I would take more time to investigate but this is due to a client earlier than expected. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried using your example to create my script. But i'm having trouble returning the full select tag. In fact having trouble returning anything even a simple string. Can the script literally look like this <?php return "hello world"; ?>

Comment: This achieved exactly what I wanted. Not what i'm used to being primarily a .NET developer, so I usually use other methods for doing this. I will remember this method and use it whenever I am programming in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you could use fill the `innerHTML` of your `<select>` box instead of a `<div>`, but I would really advise you to have a look at jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/. It makes everything a lot easier.