# PHP Mysql - how to create a dynamic drop down list using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am totally new to scripting, basically i have to try and finish a school project on a coaching tour project. The idea is to allow customers to register and book a tour.

What i am having problem with is, i have no idea on how to create a dynamic drop down list where the booking form will take the data from mysql database.

Lets say for example :

1. The customer needs to select a choice of tour i.e (industrial, cultural, military) from the first drop down list.
2. After selecting a tour, the next drop down list should list the destinations i.e. (UK, France, Germany, etc) dependant on the above (tour) choice.
3. Then the third list should show the start dates dependant on the above (destination) choice.

All the data in the drop down list should come from the database. Also when the customer submits the form, all those data should go into the customers booking table in the database.

I was told that javascript should be the answer, but i have searched so many forums and look at tutorials which they are all confusing. Hence I came to ask here! Any help on how to do this is much appreciated. Thnx!

Below is the code of how i only know how to do this:

```
           <h2><center>PLEASE PLACE YOUR BOOKING</center></h2>


<form action="booking.php" method="post">
<table width="700 border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td width="210" height="45">Tour Type:</td><td>
            <select name="tour_type">
            <option value="Cultural">Cultural</option>
            <option value="Industrial">Industrial</option>
            <option value="Military">Military</option>
     </select></td></tr>

    <tr><td width="210" height="45">Duration:</td><td>
            <select name="duration" >
            <option value="1_Day">1_Day</option>
            <option value="7_Days">7_Days</option>
            <option value="14_Days">14_Days</option>
        </select></td></tr>      

    <tr><td width="210" height="45">Destination:</td><td>
            <select name="destination" >
            <option value="England">England</option>
            <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
            <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        </select></td></tr>

    <tr><td width="210" height="45">No. of Passengers:</td><td>
            <select name="no_of_passengers" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
        </select></td></tr>

    <tr><td width="210" height="45">Depature:</td><td>
            <select name="departure" >
            <option value="13 May 2013">13 May 2013</option>
            <option value="28 May 2013">28 May 2013</option>
            <option value="11 June 2013">11 June 2013</option>
            <option value="26 June 2013">26 June 2013</option>
            <option value="14 July 2013">14 July 2013</option>
            <option value="27 July 2013">27 July 2013</option>
        </select></td></tr>

    <tr><td width="210" height="45"><input type="checkbox" name="accomodation" 
     value="YES"/>Accomodation</td></tr>
    <tr><td width="210" height="45"><input type="checkbox" name="mailshot" 
    value="YES"/>Mailshot</td></tr>
    <tr><td width="210" height="45"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</html>

    <?php
//When submit button is pressed.
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Include the server and database connection. 
include('cn.php');

session_start();

//retrieve data input from booking form and make it equal to the variable ($)
$tour_type = $_POST['tour_type'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$no_of_passengers = $_POST['no_of_passengers'];
$departure = $_POST['departure'];

// accomodation confirmation
if (isset($_POST['accomodation'] ))
{$accom = $_POST["accomodation"];
} else {
$accom = "NO";
}

// mailshot confirmation
if (isset($_POST['mailshot'] ))
{$mail = $_POST["mailshot"];
} else {
$mail = "NO";
}

$userUsername = $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];

// Build the SQL query to retreive the variables ($) and input the data into the database.
$sql = "INSERT INTO booking 
      (user_id,tour_type,duration,destination,no_of_passengers,departure,accomodation,mailshot) 
VALUES ((SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_username = '" . 
       $userUsername . "'),'$tour_type','$duration','$destination',
       '$no_of_passengers','$departure','$accom' ,'$mail')";



// test the sql statement.
if(!mysql_query($sql,$cn)) {
die(mysql_error($cn));

}
// direct to this page when booking is successful.
header('Location: booking_success.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You'll find our community much more helpful when you've posted whatever code you've attempted.  Please show us some of your work and we'll be happy to give you some advice from that point on.

Comment: plenty of examples of this on your site. if you've searched "so many forums" and tutorials, you've obviously missed looking around on SO.

Comment: sorry to ask, but how to post codes onto the forum? Is it basically copy and paste into the message box?

Comment: @kev   Just indent your code 4 spaces, and then continue normal indentation from there.  It'll format it for you

Comment: i have looked at some examples on this site, but they only show whats wrong with their codes and dont show how to get the full thing done.

Comment: @David, thnx alot i will try it now! But should i post the whole code?

Comment: @Kev.  Post your Javascript for now.  That'll at least let people know where you might be going wrong

Comment: Sorry when i try to post it, it wont let me indent it half way down the script. It keeps pushing the scripts to the left.

Comment: @David sorry for taking a while to post the code. The above code is the only way i know how to achieve a drop down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I found one guide that actually work and where he explains what he does. One thing that you should keep in mind when reading it though that it uses a different version of Jquery than the latest one, so there are a few differences in the syntax. These differences are minor though and can be found in the comments.

http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/dependable-dropdown.html

In your case it would look something like this:

## SQL

Create three tables one called id(Integer), one called master_id(Integer) and one called names(varchar).

**Id** is going to go from 1->x (meaning the last row is number x).
**master_id** is going to be 0 for the items that is in the first drop down military etc. All of the items that you want to go in to the category military will have the same value  of master_id as military has as id, for example 1. You follow this principal along with all the sub categories and dates. **name** is just a label...

## Main site php/HTML

The Html would look something like this, where you put the script in the php in the head of your site.

```
?php
try {

 $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tour', 'root', 'root');
 $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

 $sql = "SELECT * 
  FROM `region`
  WHERE `master_id` = 0";
 $statement = $objDb->query($sql);
 $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 } catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo 'There was a problem';
 }

 ?>
```

This is the forms.

```
    <select name="tour" id="tour" class="update">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <?php if (!empty($list)) { ?>
            <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <select name="location" id="location" class="update"
        disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>

    <select name="date" id="date" class="update"
        disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

Remember to add the jquery and corect path to the ajax script.

## PHP function

```
       <?php
  if (!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['value'])) {

$id = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['value'];

try {

    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tour', 'root', 'password');
    $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM `categories`
            WHERE `master` = ?";
    $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array($value));
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!empty($list)) {

        $out = array('<option value="">Select one</option>');

        foreach($list as $row) {
            $out[] = '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }

        echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => implode('', $out)));

    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}

   } else {
echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
  }
```

## ajax.js - the script

```
     var formObject = {
run : function(obj) {
    if (obj.val() === '') {
        obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        var id = obj.attr('id');
        var v = obj.val();
        jQuery.getJSON('func/tour_function.php', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----   </option>').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    }
}
  };
  $(function() {

$('.update').on('change', function() {
    formObject.run($(this));
});

 });
```

Just remember to get the paths right and to include Jquery 1.9.1 and it should work.

Comment: thnx, i will take a look and see if this works. It's just fustrating that i spent like 2 whole days sitting at this computer searching and testing and browsing forever.

Comment: I did the same! This one really works and you learn why it does what it does. It uses Ajax though, which you can see from the discussion underneath is a bit complicated. I think it is worth it though! If you wait a minuet I can show you how it would look like.

Comment: Hi there! Yes i would be grateful if you could show me please!

Comment: That was alot of code. So just put it tougher and send me a pm if it does not work. Had a shit load of problems building my first cascading drop down.

Comment: Btw what OS/environment are you testing it in?

Comment: im using windows 7 ultimate, WAMP , phpmyadmin and notepad++

Comment: Ok, then you have what you need. As I said if you have questions on the code above just add a comment or send a pm. Il be crunching data for a customer all night...

Comment: this is very helpful. I am very grateful. Cheers for the effort. i will try to use this and see if they work. BTW how do i PM you?

Comment: when you say create 3 tables, did you mean 3 fields within the booking table? i.e ID, master id and names

Comment: exactly. One database, one table, three columns.

Comment: roger! will do that now, thnx!

Comment: The link above shows you exactly how to create the table in a little nice video.

Comment: I need to leave the user_id as the (FK) in there also because it is related to the customer table ID key

Comment: I would seperate the user and the tour of choice (put them in different tables). The reason is that the user and the tour of choice are two different objects. Or did I get you right?

Comment: currently i got 2 tables: customer and booking.  The customer has cust_id, username, password, email, address, contact, gender. The booking table has booking_id, user_id (FK),type of tour, destination, duration, accomdation(YES/No) and mailshot(YES/NO). So now i have to create a tour table that will include the id, master_id and name as you mentioned above! So when the customer books a tour on the booking form, he/she should be able to use the drop down list?

Comment: That will work. Btw if you are happy with the answer given I would love for you to accept it :D

Comment: sorry the table came out in a wrong format. How do i post a table or script in here!

Comment: I think it would be best if you separate things as much as possible. Then you can solve one problem and move on to the next.

Comment: Cheers stenW i will give this a go and try to use the code you supplies above. If I have any problems i will post back here.

Comment: sent you an email. Think it describes things better.

Comment: how do i get to submit this form. Meaning when the customer clicks the submit button, it goes into the booking table in the database?

Comment: no. you should store it in a separate table.

Comment: I have tried the code which you gave via email. I did everything exactly how the tutorial did including creating the exact same table in phpmyadmin. THe whole thing doesnt work. When i open the index page from localhost, i can see the 3 drop down boxes, the first 1 is selectable (i.e. male and female) but the other 2 are greyed out(cant be selected). Any help on this?

Comment: I notice there is a mac os file included in the folder, does this have to do with anything since im using windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

To point out an answer already on this site
[Ajax approach to populating a second dynamic dropdown based on the selection in the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723564/ajax-approach-to-populating-a-second-dynamic-dropdown-based-on-the-selection-in)

Essentially, the short version would be an onchange event that loads data from your server

```
<select name="first_dropdown" onchange="$('#dropdown2_container').load('your_script.php?nid='+this.value);">
    <option....
</select>
...
<div id="dropdown2_container" style="display:none"> </div>
```

I'm not a big fan of obtrusive javascript like this, but it's a start for you.  If you want something a bit more elegant, try the following link.

http://www.99points.info/2010/12/n-level-dynamic-loading-of-dropdowns-using-ajax-and-php/

At least a bit of this should get you started.

Comment: thnx David, I will look at the link you supplied.

Comment: @Kev  Glad to help!  If one of these answers helped resolve your question, please give them an upvote and a selected answer. It shows the community that you follow through on answers provided :)

Comment: yes i would love to vote well on all the answers that were given  but it say i need 15 reputations :-(

Comment: @Kev, true, you do.  I forgot, my apologies :)

Comment: I will accept the answers though when/if i managed to fix this problem. i got limited time to work on this project because been in the military restricts me from working alot on it plus the fact that i only learnt coding for 1 week. Sorry for asking newbie question because i am totally new to coding and i have to try to teach myself how to do everything whilst trying to work on this project

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you can take.   Since you are new to scripting, I would suggest avoiding AJAX at this point.  You need something like the following:

1. On the server-side (PHP), output the data into JavaScript variables that you can work with.  For example, you could store the data in an array.

   Example: `var tours = [{ id:1, name:"Tour#1" }, { id:2, name:"Tour#2" }, etc.]`
2. You'll want to load all tour data, destination data, and start dates into the script, with enough information to link which child records belong to which parent records.
3. When the page first loads, the tour data should be populated into the first dropdown, but the second and third should be blank since they populate base on the previous ones.
4. When the user makes a change to a dropdown value (`onchange` event), then apply the logic to load the entries to the next dropdown based on the selection in the previous dropdown.

   Example: `<select id='tours' onchange='changetour();'></select>`
5. You'll also want to handle the situation where the user clears out a selection (clear out all the child selections in that case), or the user goes back to the first dropdown and changes their selection after they've already selected something in the second and third.

This should give you a rough idea of an algorithm to get started.  I would suggest giving your best effort on each item above, and come back with specific questions after you've tried writing a solution and get stuck with a specific problem.

Comment: I understand your desire to avoid confusing him, but I think AJAX is absolutely the correct approach for this particular use case.  I don't think shying away from the correct tool just because it is difficult is ever a good policy.

Comment: @DavidL: AJAX is not always the answer. Especially if you have less than a hundred rows in each dropdown (which I would guess is the case for a school project), it would be more user-friendly to have all the data preloaded to the browser.

Comment: Agreed, it is not always the answer.  That said, it wouldn't be preloaded into a browser.  The correct approach would be to filter server-side and return ONLY the applicable data set and then create options based off of that.  The paradigm of the future of web development is to allow the client to perform more and more of the heavy lifting and I don't see a reason to shy away from it here.

Comment: @DavidL: Feel free to post an AJAX-based solution :)

Comment: sorry guys, i understand what you guys mean but the thing is i really dont know how to put all this script together.

Comment: @kev: You need to break it down into steps.  Don't try to implement the whole thing at once.  Start with trying to run a query to get the data and spit it out on the page.  Can you make it that far?  Then try to get that data dumped into an array in JavaScript.  From there, try to populate a dropdown with the data.  Each of these steps can be done separately and there are many examples to solve each one.  As a programmer you'll need to develop the skill of breaking a process down into little chunks and tasks and focus on one at a time.

Comment: i have seen some tutorials where they try to do this, but honestly it just goes beyond me on how to do it! I will keep trying though even if it has to take me another 2 days. The only reason I am struggling with this, is because im in the military and i only spent 1 week learning coding where they expect us to finish this project to graduate